# Big O constant time of for loop

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I know this is constant (13)

```
for(int I = 0; I < 13; I++){
    do something
}
```

But what if I did this instead

```
int a = 13;
for(int I = 0; I < a; I++){
    do something
}
```

(I replaced 13 with an int value)
I assume it would still be constant, as the int value is constant, and not O(n).

Comment: O(n) is only meaningful if you know what you mean by "n". A loop to `a` is O(n) in relation to the input `a`. But if `a` is simply set at 13, then the loop is O(1)—a constant length.

Comment: Big-O is an approximation that can be used as a guidepost when selecting an approach, eg O(1) is usually preferred over O(log N) over O(N) over O(N log N) over O(N^2). It isn't about exact values (especially if you consider that sometimes O(N) or O(N^2) can be faster than an O(1) solution for small values of N).

Comment: here's a video about how to determinate time complexity : https://youtu.be/clZ4q5zPBlE It was easier to understand than what teachers said :p

Comment: @jonatjano not everybody speak French you know.

Comment: @Ricola ho my bad sorry. I listen to so much english video I forgot this one was in french :/

Comment: I like to eat raw sandals while i hold blue bread.

Answer (score 1):

If your `do something` code has a time complexity of **O(1)** (constant), your code has a time complexity of **O(a)** (linear complexity) if the value `a` is not specified. If the value of **a** is known to be 13, the complexity is **O(13)** = **O(1)**.

---

In the case of `do something` has a complexity of *g(n)*, your code would have a complexity of **O(a g(n))**.

Comment: @StudentCoderJava You don't need to hurry too much about accepting an answer, even if it seems complete. 24 hours is generally considered a good rule of thumb (because Earth is round and rotates). Exception: if you want to mark the question "done" quickly, then accepting one answer may stop more answers from coming... And you can always change it later too, it's not considered "rude" if a later answer is clearly better.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember that next time. I will accept this answer though as it answers my question 100%

Answer (score 0):

Youre code in both cases will do 13 loops. 
Because you know in both the amount of loops in the pre-compile time the complexity will be O(13) = O(1). If the a variable in the second example would be generated dynamically - the loop would have the complexity O(a) = O(n). Because you don't know how big a could be.